# CakePHP HABTM relationship with same model foreign keys

Tags: cakephp

I have a model 'Catgeory' that has a HABTM relationship with itself

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'SubCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_subcategories',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'subcategory_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

This is the code i'm using to save the Category. I want to create a relationship, making this category a child of parent ($id)

```
$this->Category->create();
$c["Category"]["title"] = $this->request->data["title"];
$c["SubCategory"]["CategoriesSubcategory"]["category_id"] = $id;
```

The structure seems right to me, but this does not create the relationship. However, if i try and create the relationship using

```
$c["SubCategory"]["CategoriesSubcategory"]["subcategory_id"] = $id;
```

This does work, but the parent and child are the wrong way round. So this suggested to me that the foreignKey and associationForeignKey were the wrong way round. So i then changed them around in my relationship:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'SubCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'joinTable' => 'categories_subcategories',
            'foreignKey' => 'subcategory_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

This now means the relationships get saved properly, however, i believe this relationship is the wrong way round, as when i findAll Categories, the children no longer come through in the results.

Any ideas where i am going wrong? Am i saving something wrong? Do i need to create a model SubCategory?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Tree Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html)? It might be better suited to your purpose.

Edit: Oops, just saw thanpa mentioned it already below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use a HABTM relationship - but this is just an opinion.

A category may have many subcategories so the category model must have a hasMany relationship which links to the same table with a foreing key `parent_id`.

A subcategory has always only one parent (isn't it?) so a model can be created with a relationship belongsTo.

This way you can easily save the categories and the subcategories all together and retrieve exactly what you need as well. This way you also get rid of the relation table needed for HABTM, with just another column in the categories table named parent_id or something :)

Comment: True, this is what we did before. However, seperating it into a HABTM table allowed a hierarchical array to be returned easily when find('all') on a Category. Much easier than using many for loops to sort the categories into their parents and children.

Comment: If you need hierarchical behavior then I suggest to use the Cake Tree Behavior. This will provide you with many useful methods to do what you need :) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html